# titanium: Difference between Windows and Views?

Tags: javascript, titanium

1) What is the difference between a window and a view?

2) A window is a new screen or a view is a new screen? or both?

3) What if you had a simple form with 3 screens

```
"Form Detail ---> Form Review ---> Form Confirm/Submit"
```

Will I create 3 windows or 3 views? what about 1 window and 3 views?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window)

> The Window is an empty drawing surface or container.
>
> A window is a top-level container which can contain other views. Windows can be opened and closed. Opening a window causes the window and its child views to be added to the application's render stack, on top of any previously opened windows. Closing a window removes the window and its children from the render stack.
>
> Windows contain other views, but in general they are not contained inside other views.

So a window is like a container for the views you want to draw (yes, like a screen).  How you want to do it (3 windows vs 3 screens) is up to you.  However, those views are so similar that it makes more sense to me to keep them in the same window and just alter the view.

Comment: Im guessing what you would do in this case is create 1 window, with 3 views - right?

Comment: Oops, I meant 3 windows vs 3 views above.  Yes, I would create 3 views, or better yet just create 1 view and alter it (Detail and Review should change only slightly right?)